# Wrapfigure without line break

Tags: line-breaking, wrapfigure

Ok so here is a question for all of you latex experts. Every time I use the **\wrapfigure{}** environment I get the following:

[image: Notice how there is line skip right after a period. and it separates the text.] 
(Notice how in this 1st image there is a line skip right after a period which separates the text.)

But what I really want is this:

[image]

Maybe is not possible to achieve this with a simple **\wrapfigure{}** but if someone knows how to do it I would really appreciate the help.
Thank you hand happy Latexing!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5):

It's easy using the plain TeX macro package `insbox`.  However, it does not accept floats, so you have to put the graphic in a `\parbox` of the relevant width,, and use `\captionof{figure}{...}`.

The syntax is the following for insertion on the right side `\InsertBoxR{no of unshortened lines}{object to be inserted}[optional integer]`. The optional argument is the number of supplementary  short lines, in case TeX doesn't calculate the exact number of short lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt, latin]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{3}{\parbox{0.35\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{traccia-table}%
\captionof{figure}{Traccia table}}}[6]

\lipsum[8-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm very fast. Good point +1.

Comment: The legs of the table helped me… ;o)

Comment: Are there any drawbacks (except no automatic floating) of `insbox` compared to `wrapfig`?

Comment: @Skillmon: I don't know really. I began to use it in places where `wrapfig` can't work, such as lists. It doesn't work with lists ‘as is’, but we can add some commands to bypass the problems.

Comment: @Bernard are you willing to show me how [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417516/wrapped-figures-using-insbox-in-lists)?

Comment: Unfortunately this command messes up other figures in any following sections for me.

Answer (score 1):

This does look good. I typed the text and looked for a natural line break.
There I put the `wrapfigure` environment. I admit this is a poor solution, but it works. This is also the solution mentioned in the package documentation (page 2 -- as the last bullet point in the first bullet list on that page):

> It is convenient to begin the environment between paragraphs, but if you want placement in the middle of a paragraph, you must put the environment between two words where there is a natural line break.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig,blindtext}

\begin{document}
This is my awesome paragraph with a \texttt{wrapfigure} environment. Let's see
how we can do this real quick. I'm adding some more manual text just to fill
some lines and then let the \texttt{wrapfigure} environment start. This way it
gets% a line break did occur here
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
closer to what you want. And here goes some more \blindtext.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using your idea without noticing. Maybe there would be another package to help with this in the future. Thanks again for replying so quickly. Greetings from Manchester. :)