# Wrapped Figures Using `insbox` in Lists

Tags: insbox

At [this
comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417437/wrapfigure-without-line-break/417439#comment1043818_417454)
Bernard claims that `insbox` does work in lists if we add some commands. Now I
wonder which commands enable us to do this.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \InsertBoxR{2}{\parbox{2cm}{\rule{2cm}{1cm}\captionof{figure}{foo}}}
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I do it: I defines a `\wrapitem` command, which patches `\item`, and an `\InsertListR` command, patching `\InsertBoxR`, and which must follow immediately `\wrapitem`. The other  items use the standard `\item` command.

It works fine as long as the inserted item does not overflow into the next item, and is adapted to the standard right-alignment of the labels. I guess it could be adapted to the left-aligned case (such as with the `wide` option), but I didn't do it. It also can be easily adapted to `enumerate` environments.

If the image overflows the next item, a work-around consists in splitting the itemize environment into several, playing with the `resume*`and `before` options of `enumitem`. I give an example in the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \newcommand*{\wrapitem}{\apptocmd{\labelitemi}{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}\item\apptocmd{\labelitemi}{\hskip-\leftmargin}{}{}}
    \newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][]{%
    \mbox{}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]%
    }%

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \wrapitem%
 \InsertListR{2}{~\parbox{2cm}{\color{WhiteSmoke}\rule{2cm}{1cm}\captionof{figure}{foo}}}%
 Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ul-
tricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula
aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hen-
drerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum
turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}%[leftmargin =2cm]%
  \wrapitem%
 \InsertListR[7]{2}{~\parbox{2cm}{\color{Gold!50}\rule{2cm}{3cm}\captionof{figure}{foo}}}%
 \lipsum[2]
 \end{itemize}
%
 \begin{itemize}[resume*, rightmargin = 2.5cm]
\item%
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo.
\end{itemize}
%
 \begin{itemize}[resume*, before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+2\topsep+\partopsep}]
\item[]%
Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Skillmon: I've posted a sample of what I can do – which is far from perfect…

Comment: I built upon your sample [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453624/117050). It isn't thoroughly tested but extents your approach to work without the use of separate `itemize` environments.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thank you. I'll try to test, and report if there's any problem :-)