# Wrapping itemize around figure using floatflt in multicol environment - figure doesn't show

Tags: itemize, multicol

I'm doing a poster, using a the a0poster style, and I was trying to wrap a itemize list around a figure. I tried the wrapfigure package, but I gathered it doesn't work with itemize lists, so I tried floatflt, which is supposed to work fine with lists (provided you use \fltitem). My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2} 

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{floatingfigure}[r]{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{universe.jpg}
\caption{very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption}
\label{fig:example}
\end{floatingfigure}

\begin{itemize}
    \fltitem{one very very very very very long text}
    \fltitem{two very very very very very long text}
    \fltitem{three very very very very very long text}
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[4-7]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

which results in (notice the absence of image next to the list):

[image: MWE render]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following builds upon https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417571/117050 but extends it a lot. It defines the macros:

- `\InsertListR[<correction>]{<skip>}{<contents>}` with the arguments `<correction>` being a correction factor as used by `insbox` (use it to extend the amount of lines affected), `<skip>` being a number of lines to skip before the insertion and `<contents>` being a box which is to be inserted.
- `\wrapitem` used to start the first item after which you use `\InsertListR`
- `\contitem` another item after you used `\InsertListR` which should also be affected. It takes an optional argument specifying the number of affected lines (defaulting to a whooping 100)
- `\EndInsert` to manually stop the effects of an `\InsertListR` or any of the other `insbox` macros. It also starts a new paragraph. If the indentation should be suppressed you can use the starred version.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{duckuments}% funnier than lipsum
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*\wrapitem
  {%
    \apptocmd\labelitemi{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}% add a correction
    \item
    \patchcmd\labelitemi{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}{}% remove the added hskip
  }
\newsavebox\InsertListRbox
\newlength\InsertListPrevWidth
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][]
  {%
    \mbox{}%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \setbox\InsertListRbox\hbox{#3}%
    \global\InsertListPrevWidth
      \dimexpr
        \wd\InsertListRbox+\@InsertBoxMargin
      \relax
    \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin\box\InsertListRbox\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]%
  }%
\newcommand*\contitem[1][100]
  {%
    \item
      \ParShape=3
                {0}  0cm 0cm
                {#1} 0cm {\the\InsertListPrevWidth}
                1    0cm 0cm
  }
\newcommand*\EndInsert
  {
    \@restore@
    \@ifstar{\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}{}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindduck[1]
\begin{multicols}{0}
  \section{Introduction}
  \blindduck[-5]
  \begin{itemize}
    \wrapitem
    \InsertListR{0}
      {%
        \parbox{.48\columnwidth}
          {%
            \includegraphics[width=.48\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
            \captionof{figure}{foo}%
          }%
      }%
    one very very very very very long text
    \contitem two very very very very very long text
    \contitem three very very very very very long text
  \end{itemize}
  \EndInsert*
  \blindduck[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

**EDIT:** More reasonable default for `\contitem`. By default this version does the same calculation `insbox` is doing to calculate the number of the affected lines. You can give the number explicitly if you're not satisfied with the results. It also changes the default value of `\InsertListR` to be a reasonable `0` (an empty default argument would be the same as 1, which won't be the expected behaviour from `insbox`).

Also for reasons I don't yet understand, the effect of `\InsertListR` is ended by the next new paragraph after the `itemize` environment. I therefore added a macro `\MoreInsert` which takes as its argument the number of lines which should be affected in the current paragraph (only in the current, another new paragraph ends its effect).

New code (in a complete MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{duckuments}% funnier than lipsum
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*\wrapitem
  {%
    \apptocmd\labelitemi{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}% add a correction
    \item
    \patchcmd\labelitemi{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}{}% remove the added hskip
  }
\newlength\InsertListPrevWidth
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][0]
  {%
    \mbox{}%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]%
    \global\InsertListPrevWidth\@framewidth
  }%
\newcommand*\contitem[1][\the\count1]
  {%
    \item
    \bgroup  % to keep some changes local
      % let's calculate parameters for \ParShape
      \def\reserved@a{#1}%
      \def\reserved@b{\the\count1}%
      \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b
        % Below calculation is copied from \@@InsertBox of insbox
        \dimen0 = \@wherebottom
        \advance \dimen0 by -\pagetotal
        \divide \dimen0 by \baselineskip
        \count1 = \dimen0
        \advance \count1 by 1
        \advance \count1 by -\@numnormal
      \fi
      \MoreInsert{#1}%
    \egroup
  }
\newcommand*\EndInsert
  {%
    \@restore@
    \@ifstar{\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}{}%
  }
\newcommand*\MoreInsert[1]
  {%
    \ParShape = 2
                {#1}   0cm   {\the\InsertListPrevWidth}
                1      0cm   0cm
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindduck[1]
\begin{multicols}{0}
  \section{Introduction}
  \blindduck[-5]
  \begin{itemize}
    \wrapitem
    \InsertListR{0}
      {%
        \parbox{.48\columnwidth}
          {%
            \includegraphics[width=.48\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}%
            \captionof{figure}{foo}%
          }%
      }%
    one very very very very very long text
    \contitem two very very very very very long text
    \contitem three very very very very very long text
  \end{itemize}

  \MoreInsert{1}
  \blindduck[1-5]

  \blindduck[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked wonders, thank you very much! Quick add-on question, if I want to slightly increase the distance between the list on the left and the caption/figure, what should I change?

Comment: @RuiApóstolo include `\makeatletter\@InsertBoxMargin=<length>\makeatother` in your preamble after `\input{insbox.tex}`. Obviously `<length>` should be the width you want to use. Default of `insbox` is `2mm` if I remember correctly.

Comment: Just to add (in case someone else needs it) the package `\usepackage{caption}` breaks this solution (especially the `\MoreInsert` command. I changed to `\usepackage{capt-of}` like @Skillmon has on their example and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @RuiApóstolo for me it works flawlessly with `caption`, generating identical output as with `capt-of` in my test cases.

Comment: Might have been my particular combination of packages then, I'm also using `xcolor` and `contour` on my figure captions. But as I said, with `capt-of` all works.

Comment: @RuiApóstolo can you please provide a minimal example where above commands fail? Without a document reproducing the issues I can't look into it, but it might be of great value for future visitors.

Comment: I feel like I might be missing something really basic here, and if so, apologies for wasting your time. You can find a MWE on overleaf (no account needed to open code) [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/swxxkgpmgfbk). Image used can be found [here](https://pixabay.com/en/duck-water-bird-mallard-rush-2767920/).

Comment: @RuiApóstolo The reason why `\MoreInsert` isn't working in your code is because you start a new paragraph after using it (the empty line). As mentioned in my edit, it has to be used inside of the paragraph (put the empty line from below `\MoreInsert` above it). Also in this case you'd have to use the optional argument of `\contitem` because the default calculation fails (this is due to the additional spacing around the items in an `itemize` environment).

Comment: I'm very sorry, I completely missed that detail regarding the `\MoreInsert` command.

I went back to my previous version of the poster, and it seems that had I use the optional argument of `\contitem` it would have been fine.

If you don't mind me asking: why does `\contitem` fail on a 3 line paragraph when it defaults to 100, does it have to do with the combination of word lengths and column widths?

Comment: @RuiApóstolo if you use my second code block, it doesn't use the default of 100, but instead the calculation done by `insbox` and that one fails (I assume because of the different spacing in `itemize` environments, but am not completely sure atm). If time (and the original author) permits I'll try to write a package using a similar approach as `insbox` to solve the problem in LaTeX (which will then hopefully be list aware). I'm currently reading the sources of `wrapfig` and plan to read the sources of other packages resolving around text-floating as well.