# How to wrap a figure in exam document?

Tags: exam, wrapfigure

I can wrap in ARTICLE, but not in EXAM. How to wrap in EXAM?
(Question Plus-if you´re a LaTeX master-.- What´s the mosr suitable and easy package to do this kind of things?)

I can wrap a figure in an ARTICLE document

with this code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
%\begin{questions}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}
    \caption{This is A}
\end{wrapfigure}
Hello, I want to wrap this figure in exam
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1]
%\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BUT I´d like wrap images in EXAM documents, and this code doesn´t give the wrapped figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}
    \caption{This is A}
\end{wrapfigure}
\question Hello, I want to wrap this figure in exam
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1]

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**

### EDITED (2019/02/24) Afther trying Skillmon solution, I have a new problem with lists(enumerate) in the questions

**

This is the problem
[image]

With the code (only adding itemize in  thq euestion with the figure)

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{exam}
        \usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
        \input{insbox}
        \usepackage{capt-of}
        \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
        \usepackage{mwe}

        \usepackage{etoolbox}

        \makeatletter
        %% Stealing some code from exam:
        \def\mypointshandling
          {%>>>
            \if@bonus
              \def\padded@point@block{%
            \begingroup
              \@placepointstrue
              \bonuspoint@block
            \endgroup
              }%
            \else
              \def\padded@point@block{%
            \begingroup
              \@placepointstrue
              \point@block
            \endgroup
              }%
            \fi
            \if@pointsdropped
            \else
              \if@bonus
            \if@bonusqformat
              \ifx\ques@ref\@queslevel
              \else
                \setup@point@toks
              \fi
            \else
              \setup@point@toks
            \fi
              \else
            \if@qformat
              \ifx\ques@ref\@queslevel
              \else
                \setup@point@toks
              \fi
            \else
              \setup@point@toks
            \fi
              \fi
            \fi
            \global \MyIfPointsfalse
          }%<<<
        \newif\ifMyIfPoints
        \protected\def\questionInsbox
          {%
            \@ifnextchar[\questionInsbox@a{\questionInsbox@a[]}%
          }
        \protected\long\def\questionInsbox@a[#1]#2#3%
          {%
            \@ifnextchar[{\questionInsbox@b{#1}{#2}{#3}}
              {\questionInsbox@b{#1}{#2}{#3}[0]}
          }
        \long\def\questionInsbox@b#1#2#3[#4]%
          {%
            \apptocmd\@itemlabel{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}%
            \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
            \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
              \question
            \else
              \global\MyIfPointstrue
              \patchcmd\@readpoints{\global\@placepointstrue}{\relax}{}{}%
              \question[#1]%
              \patchcmd\@readpoints{\relax}{\global\@placepointstrue}{}{}%
            \fi
            \patchcmd\@itemlabel{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}{}%
            \let\makelabel\@mklab
            \mbox{}%
            \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
            \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
            \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#4]%
            \ifMyIfPoints
              \mypointshandling
            \fi
            \the\point@toks
            \ignorespaces
          }
        \makeatother

        \begin{document}
        \begin{questions}
          \question Jei you
          \questionInsbox[5]{0}
            {%
              \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}
            {%
              \centering
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}
              \captionof{figure}{This is A}%
            }%
            }[1]
        Hello, I want to wrap this figure in exam, and you should choose the rigth answer:
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item \lipsum[1]  
          \item \lipsum[1]
        \end{enumerate}

        \question Another
        \end{questions}
        \end{document}
```

The solution, not the best but... on the fly I have typed is:

```
\question See figure and answer, please:    
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{multicols}{2}  
\item answer 1
\item ans 2
\item ans 3
{\centering
    \begingroup
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=1.00\linewidth]{{example-image-a.png}
                \vspace{-0.3cm}
                \captionof{figure}{}
                \label{fig:croquis-rectangulo-ecuacions.png}
            \endgroup}
  \end{multicols}
  \item ans afeter fig
  \end{enumerate}
```

**EDIT (2019/02/25) after EDIT 3 of Skillmon** 
I admire yout knowledge of LaTeX programming. It´s fantastic!!

The solution if perfect for normal text but when you use lists (enumerate, itemize,...) the problem is remaining.
After reading the last comments (2019/02/24) of Skillmon, I decide to simulate the lists in normal text. With 
    \
    a) answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1\
    b) answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2 answer 2\

LaTeX is so beatifull, so complicated!!

Waiting for this option (I´m optimistic, yes!! :-) ) in exam class in the future... I´ll use your solutions sometimes.

Only fails in the bottom of page, as far as I can see, and when you use some \questionInsboxL[5]{2} with close to blank page between questions.

THANK YOU FOR ALL YOUR SOLUTIONS AND EFFORTS!

[image]

**THANK YOU, SKILLMON**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`wrapfig` doesn't work in lists, and `questions` is just another version of a list. The following is a quick and dirty reimplementation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453624/117050 to work with `enumerate` like lists instead of with `itemize`. It uses `insbox` just like @Bernard's answer, but shouldn't require a manual paragraph. It does only implement the code to wrap inside one question, not inside the next one, too.

**EDIT:** It now should support `exam`'s points system, but I didn't test it thoroughly. You might come back and complain if it doesn't work out.

**EDIT2:** Streamlined the interface to be more like the one of `\InsertBoxR`, the new macro's name is `\questionInsboxR` and it takes an optional argument, two mandatory ones, and a second optional one. The first optional argument is like the one of `\question`, the two mandatory arguments and the following optional one are like those of `\InsertBoxR`.

**EDIT3:** Added `\questionInsboxL`, fixed behaviour of multiple `\questionInsboxL/R` usages inside one `questions` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
%% Stealing some code from exam:
\def\mypointshandling
  {%>>>
    \if@bonus
      \def\padded@point@block{%
        \begingroup
          \@placepointstrue
          \bonuspoint@block
        \endgroup
      }%
    \else
      \def\padded@point@block{%
        \begingroup
          \@placepointstrue
          \point@block
        \endgroup
      }%
    \fi
    \if@pointsdropped
    \else
      \if@bonus
        \if@bonusqformat
          \ifx\ques@ref\@queslevel
          \else
            \setup@point@toks
          \fi
        \else
          \setup@point@toks
        \fi
      \else
        \if@qformat
          \ifx\ques@ref\@queslevel
          \else
            \setup@point@toks
          \fi
        \else
          \setup@point@toks
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \global \MyIfPointsfalse
  }%<<<
\protected\long\def\myOargparse#1#2%>>>
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[{\myOargparse@{#2}}{#2{#1}}%
  }%<<<
\long\def\myOargparse@#1[#2]%>>>
  {%
    #1{#2}%
  }%<<<
\def\q@mark{\q@mark}
\newif\ifMyIfPoints
\newif\if@notfirstins
\protected\def\questionInsboxL%>>>
  {%
    \myOargparse{\q@mark}{\questionInsbox@a\InsertBoxL}%
  }%<<<
\protected\def\questionInsboxR%>>>
  {%
    \myOargparse{\q@mark}{\questionInsbox@a\InsertBoxR}%
  }%<<<
\protected\long\def\questionInsbox@a#1#2#3#4%>>>
  {%
    \myOargparse{0}{\questionInsbox@b{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
  }%<<<
\protected\long\def\questionInsbox@b#1#2#3#4#5%>>>
  {%
    \if@notfirstins
    \else
      \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
      \apptocmd\@itemlabel{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}%
    \fi
    \ifx\q@mark#2%
      \question
    \else
      \global\MyIfPointstrue
      \patchcmd\@readpoints{\global\@placepointstrue}{\relax}{}{}%
      \question[{#2}]%
      \patchcmd\@readpoints{\relax}{\global\@placepointstrue}{}{}%
    \fi
    \if@notfirstins
    \else
      \patchcmd\@itemlabel{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}{}%
      \let\makelabel\@mklab
      \@notfirstinstrue
    \fi
    \mbox{}%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \ifx\InsertBoxR#1%
      #1{#3}{\hskip-\leftmargin#4\hskip\leftmargin}[{#5}]%
    \else
      #1{\numexpr#3+1\relax}{#4}[{#5}]\par\hspace{\itemindent}%
    \fi
    \ifMyIfPoints
      \mypointshandling
    \fi
    \the\point@toks
    \ignorespaces
  }%<<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question[5]\lipsum[2]
  \questionInsboxR[5]{0}
    {%
      \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}
        {%
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}%
          \captionof{figure}{This is A}%
        }%
    }[1]
    Hello, I want to wrap this figure in exam
    \lipsum[1]
  \questionInsboxL[5]{2}
    {%
      \parbox[t]{.3\linewidth}
        {%
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}%
          \captionof{figure}{This is A}%
        }%
    }[1]
    Hello, I want to wrap this figure in exam
    \lipsum[1]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Skillmom the solutions it´s exactly how I liked. We need to add many code lines, but the result it´s exactly how I liked. With the tabulars/indents as \question of exam docs.

Comment: Is possible another \questionInsbox with option for Left figure instead of Right figure?

Comment: @MikaIke that's why we need so many code lines, because we want all those indents to be kept, and that's only possible with wobbling a bit with internals of `exam` and lists (and 40 lines are just a simple copy of some code of `exam` to use it elsewhere). See my new edit for figures on the left and right.

Comment: Thank you for solution @Skillmon Now I have another problem, with the answers in a enumerate. I post it in a new EDIT 2019/02/24 in the original question.

Comment: @MikaIke nesting inside `itemize` or `enumerate` is different. This solution is tailored to work inside of `questions` with a `\question`. For a solution that works in `itemize` instead, see the link I refer to in my answer. The situation with different types of lists is less than ideal and each type of list needs its own set of adaptations to make the `insbox` solution work. I originally planned to write a package which tries to tackle this, but up till now I didn't succeed in doing so (and in fact this question didn't contribute to my motivation) :)

Comment: @MikaIke as of now, there is no code supporting `enumerate`. I might come up with something.

Comment: @MikaIke and nesting is something I haven't solved yet, too.

Comment: @MikaIke maybe it's better to simply not use this with nested lists as of now.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution with `caption` and the plain TeX `insbox` macro package. It defines a `\InsertBoxR` command, to be inserted at the very beginning of a paragraph, which takes two mandatory arguments: the number of untouched lines before a box id inserted, and the inserted box itself. In addition, in case TeX has a wrong computation of number of the necessary shorter lines, it accepts as an optional argument the number of supplementary shorter lines that you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question
Hello, I want to wrap this figure in exam. \par
\InsertBoxR {0}{\parbox{0.3\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}\captionof{figure}{This is A}}}[3]
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1]
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, it is advised to use the `capt-of` package, if the only application of the `caption` package would be `\captionof`.

Comment: You're probably right. However, I systematically load it for another reason: when you put   captions above tables (as is the typographical tradition, for obvious reasons), LaTeX does not swap the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`, whence captions much too close to tables, whereas  `caption` does.

Comment: I know. The above is only the advise given by the documentation of `caption` as well. And thanks again for sharing your `insbox`+`itemize` magic to me :)

Comment: @Bernard I like the solution. It´s not complicated (little code) but the tabulars/indent are not ok in all the questions https://i.imgur.com/BUH1Brt.jpg

Comment: I didn't try to delve into the `exam` code  — I don't use this package, and don't have the expertise for that. Skillmon did a really fine job.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the compliment :) I haven't used the `exam` package myself, just delved a bit into it to see whether this solution can be made to work with it, and to my surprise, it is possible (though the problematic of nested lists remains). Somebody should really write a package for this...