# exam/wrapfigure: Text doesn't wrap around the figure

Tags: wrapfigure, lipsum

For the following MWE, why is the first image overlayed with the text when using `\lipsum` instead of pasting dummy text?

And how to fix the other two images to be placed properly next to their respective texts?

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{adjustbox,wrapfig,lipsum}

\newenvironment{mywrapfigure}
{%
    \setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}%
    \wrapfloat{figure}%
}
{\endwrapfloat}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mywrapfigure}{r}{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{mywrapfigure}

    \lipsum[1]

    \bigskip
    \begin{questions}
        \question

        \begin{mywrapfigure}{r}{0.3\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{mywrapfigure}

        \lipsum[1]

        \bigskip
        \begin{parts}

            \part[4]

            \begin{mywrapfigure}{r}{0.3\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            \end{mywrapfigure}

            \lipsum[1]

        \end{parts}

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is a bug in the lipsum package https://github.com/patta42/lipsum/issues/16.

Comment: My suggestion, ditch `lipsum` and use `duckuments` instead with `\blindduck`. If you then use `\blindduck[1-]` it will then use only one paragraph but correctly add a `\par` after it.

Comment: But nevertheless you will have issues getting wrapping figures in `\question` or `\part` stuff using `wrapfig`. Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476381/

Comment: @Skillmon it is not a quick fix as I assumed. Thanks for sharing this with me.

Comment: I am voting to close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476381/2288.

Comment: @Diaa note that my answer there doesn't deal with `parts` and I'm at least somewhat sure that it will not work out of the box in `parts`. So it might be a good idea to ask a follow up if you need it to work there automatically.