# What messes up the space between the second itemlabel and text in this example?

Tags: graphics, lists, wrap

I am trying to wrap pictures around list environments. I've found this question: [Wrapping itemize around figure using floatflt in multicol environment - figure doesn't show](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453619/wrapping-itemize-around-figure-using-floatflt-in-multicol-environment-figure-d/453624#453624) And the answer of this question is working almost perfectly.

One of the problems I've noticed is that if I am trying to make two points with `\itempicture` (from my code) in one list then something makes the second number point be further away from the text.

Can somebody point out why and help to fix this?

PS. I see that `\end{enumerate}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\begin{enumerate}[resume*]` between `itempictures` actually solves this problem. But I'm genuinely interested what am I missing.

[image: spa]

MY MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{xargs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, footskip = 1 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{printlen}   

\newcommand*\wrapitem{%
    \apptocmd\labelenumi{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}% add a correction
    \item
    \patchcmd\labelenumi{\hskip\leftmargin}{}{}{}% remove the added hskip
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\InsertListR}[3][0]{%
    \mbox{}%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}%
    \InsertBoxR{#2}{\hskip-\leftmargin#3\hskip\leftmargin}[#1]%
}%

\newcommand{\itempicture}[3][5]{    
    \wrapitem
    \InsertListR[#1]{0}{\begin{threeparttable}\begin{tabular}{c@{}}\captionsetup{type=figure}\includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth]{#2}\end{tabular}\captionof{figure}{}\label{#2}\end{threeparttable}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\itempicture[5]{example-image-a}{0.15}
\lipsum[1]
\itempicture[5]{example-image-a}{0.15}
\lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is in insbox.tex people cannot tat the mwe without it. Is it relevant?

Comment: @daleif it's a generic pack­age which is very useful when wrapping images and insbox often works better than other packages, because it's based on plain TeX. https://ctan.org/pkg/insbox And yes, it is the the most important part.