# List-like paragraphs without a list env

Tags: lists, indentation, wrapfigure

I have a document with a set of paragraphs where each paragraph has a label/caption.
I need an unusual behavior:

- The label should be on the same line as the first line of the paragraph
- The paragraph should be indented, but the label should be *not* indented (ie. placed on the left of the paragraph some distance)
- If the label is larger than the indent, it should bump the first line a bit
  to fit (and there should be a space between the two)

So far I'm doing this with a description list env:

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin=3em,style=nextline,itemsep=1ex]
```

This works really well, but there's one problem: I can't use `wrapfig`, because `wrapfig` doesn't play with lists.

Is there a way to do the same thing without the environment `description` so that I can use `wrapfig` too?

Comment: There should (hopefully) be a way without wrapfig: with the plain TeX macropackage `insbox`.

Comment: @Bernard hmm... I've looked into how that's done ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453619/wrapping-itemize-around-figure-using-floatflt-in-multicol-environment-figure-d/453624#453624)) and honestly that seems pretty complex...

Comment: There are other examples on this site, as far as I remember. However, maybe I've misunderstood your problem: You do have to insert an image?

Comment: Yes, I would like to insert an image :-)

Comment: Well, to be fair, hacking into the list-like environments is hard, so yes, the solution with at least some degree of auto-spacing using `insbox` is complicated (and has to be adapted differently for the different list environments). Faking a `description` is certainly possible, but I'm not sure how well this plays with `wrapfig` either. Can you please create a minimal example?

Comment: I have since figured I can emulate the list with a `\tabto`, [like this](https://gist.github.com/vojtechkral/9ae595c89718443489795b9cc1aa8300). It's not particularly elegant as there needs to be a `\tabto` on each line, but I actually generate that TeX with a script so that's not an issue, if it can't be done more elegantly.
Sorry, I'm not very experienced with TeX.

Comment: Why not do this with a sectioning command instead of a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following defines a very simple minded `fakedescription` environment (one could further enhance it by instead of defining custom lengths for the spacing pick up the spaces defined by LaTeX (or `enumitem`) for the real `description` environment). It should work with `wrapfig` (the following has a small demonstration using `wrapfig`, but I did no extensive testing whatsoever).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\makeatletter
\newlength\fakedescription@indent
\newlength\fakedescription@labelsep
\newlength\fakedescription@itemsep
\newlength\fakedescription@topsep
\newcommand\fakeitem[1][]
  {%
    \GenericError{}
      {Error: Usage of \string\fakeitem\space outside of fakedescription}
      {}
      {}%
  }
\AtBeginDocument
  {% setting AtBeginDocument since earlier we can't rely on em being correct
    \fakedescription@indent=3em
    \fakedescription@labelsep=1em
    \fakedescription@itemsep=\smallskipamount
    \fakedescription@topsep=\medskipamount
  }
\newenvironment{fakedescription}
  {%
    \par
    \vspace\fakedescription@topsep
    \renewcommand\fakeitem[1][]
      {%
        \par
        \vskip\fakedescription@itemsep
        \noindent\kern-\fakedescription@indent
        \sbox0{\textbf{##1}}%
        \ifdim\wd0>\dimexpr
                   \fakedescription@indent-\fakedescription@labelsep\relax
          \usebox0\kern\fakedescription@labelsep
        \else
          \makebox[\fakedescription@indent][l]{\usebox0}%
        \fi
        \ignorespaces
      }%
    \advance\leftskip\fakedescription@indent
    \ignorespaces
  }
  {%
    \par
    \vspace\fakedescription@topsep
    \@endpetrue
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\blindduck[-]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}[0pt]{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{fakedescription}
  \fakeitem[A] the first one letter of the Latin alphabet
  \fakeitem[AB] the first two letters of the Latin alphabet
  \fakeitem[ABC] the first three letters of the Latin alphabet
  \fakeitem[ABCD] the first four letters of the Latin alphabet
  \fakeitem[ABCDE] the first five letters of the Latin alphabet
  \fakeitem[story] \blindduck[-]
\end{fakedescription}
\blindduck[-]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks a lot man.